# icomoon fonts not showing on being deployed

Tags: html, css, fonts

my sample website is www.peshaa.com

I am playing around with icomoon fonts and used their icon-droplet.It is supposed to be appearing right before the text "religions of the world" but all I get is a rectangle in all the browsers.However, when I test my html/css code locally, the icon-droplet font appears perfectly in all the browsers. When I debug, am getting 404 error file not found. My CSS is as follows

`@font-face {`

```
font-family: 'icomoon';
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot');
src:url('fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
url('fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are your paths correct?

Comment: yes, my paths are correct or else they wouldn't be working locally.

Comment: ok.got it working. when downloading the fonts from icomoon apps, click on the preferences tab and select base 64 encode & embed fonts in css option before downloading the files.That will make it show up.

Comment: I've never had to do that. Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: Once your issue is resolved, you can close the question or answer your own question for future readers. Please don't leave it as "Unanswered". Cheers!

Comment: Use this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998838/how-to-use-easily-icomoon-icon-to-website-change-colour-of-icon-and-adding-more/55999027#55999027

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by removing `?#iefix` and `icomoon`!

Weird!

Comment: Why did removing these fix your problem? These seem to be standard browser compatibility 'extensions'

Comment: He Can you tell me how to use icomoon fonts in local project. i am not getting syntax. I have downloaded icomoon.zip which contains demofiles, fonts folder and demo.html, Read me.txt, selection.json and style.css.