# @font-face icons not showing

Tags: css, .htaccess, fonts, font-face

I have a problem with my icomoon icons not showing.

Locally they work fine, however i uploaded my site and they are not showing.
Console has 404 however they are in the correct dir.

I updated my .htaccess to setup ttf and woff types

Following this https://gist.github.com/WheresAlice/843983

I also tried removing the `?#iefix` via the last answer on this [icomoon fonts not showing on being deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544465/icomoon-fonts-not-showing-on-being-deployed)

but still doesnt work.

Whats weird is that if i visit my site via ip i can see the icons?

Any one have any idea?

http://www.black-marked.com/ - icons dont work

http://79.170.40.236/black-marked.com/ - icons work

Comment: Can you show the codes? and is there any error shown in console? also look into Network tab for 404 items as well.

Comment: No matter which link I click, I always end up on the site without the IP numbers, and the icons don't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question incase anyone else has this problem.

I had to do a fresh download from icomoon (the values on the end of the css had changed since my last localhost download)

removed the icon folder and css from the server to clear the cache then uploaded the icons and css again. This seemed to fix it.